# How to display a hasMany() relationship through a table in a view.

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display a table in my view with contents that consists of information from my Location table (Addr, City, etc...)  and Resource table (Name, Descr.), they're linked by ID's through a ResourceLocation Table.  Here's what I have so far:

**Resource Controller**

```html
....

public function resource()
{
    $resources = Resource::all();
    return view('pages.resource', compact('resources'));
}

public function location()
{
    $locations = Location::all
    return view (compact('locations'));
}

public function resourcelocation()
{
    $resourcelocations = ResourceLocation::all();
    return view (compact ('resourcelocations'));
}

...
```

**ResourceLocation Model**

```html
/**
 * Class ResourceLocation
 */
class ResourceLocation extends Model
{
   ...

    public function resource ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Resource');
    }

    public function location ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Location');
    }      
}
```

**Resource Model**

```html
/**
 * Class Resource
 */
class Resource extends Model
{

...

/** A resource can have many locations */

  public function location()
  {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ResourceLocation');
  }       
}
```

**Location Model**

```html
/**
 * Class Location
 */
class Location extends Model
{
...
    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ResourceLocation');
    }  
}
```

**resource.blade.php**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Resource Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Zip Code</th>
      <th>County</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach ($resourcelocations as $resourcelocation)
  <tr>
      <td> {{ $resourcelocation->id }}</td>
      <td>
      @foreach ($resourcelocation->resources as $resource)
            {{ $resource->Name }},
      @endforeach
      </td>
      <td>
      @foreach($resourcelocations->locations as $location)
            {{ $location->City }}
                    @endforeach
      </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
</table>
```

I just wanted to add a column or two to see if it was working, but I keep getting an undefined variable on `resourcelocations`, still trying to wrap my head around laravel and how the relationships work, so maybe my logic is messed up. Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in your relationships.  I think it could work with the way you have it but you are making it much more confusing than it needs to be.

First, start with removing the `ResourceLocation` model.  You can relate `resources` and `locations` directly without need of the intermediary model (you will still need that table though).  This is what's called a belongs-to-many relationship.

I also recommend when you have a relationship which can return many records (for example if a resource can have many locations) you should name the method which relates these `locations` rather than `location`.

With all that in mind, your `Resource` model gets...

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location', 'ResourceLocation');
}
```

Where I put `'ResourceLocation'`, that should be whatever you named your pivot table.

Same for your `Location` model which receives.

```
public function resources()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Resource', 'ResourceLocation');
}
```

Now that should be greatly simplified, we just replaced 4 relationship methods and 3 models for 2 relationship methods and 2 models.

Now for your controller, it's much more efficient to use eager loading to grab all your resource locations.

```
$resources = Resource::with('locations')->get();
```

And in your view...

```
@foreach ($resources as $resource)
    @foreach ($resource->locations as $location)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $resource->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $location->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know you can join the two tables by just using that statement, I was thinking of SQL join statements.  **EDIT** Nevermind, the namespaces were different from. Progress, I see the tables, just no data.

Comment: The `belongsToMany` function takes additional parameters for the ids.  If yours are different than what Laravel expects, it likely wouldn't return data.  What are the names of your id's in your `ResourceLocation` table?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out.  instead of `{{ $resource->name}}` it was `Name` in my database, so everything was just blank.  After I capitalized them all, the data showed correctly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your **Resource Controller** you are not passing any `resourcelocation` variable as I can see only `resources` has been called. try declaring the variable in array in this line `return view('pages.resource', compact('resources'));`

To get the first element in `hasMany` you can try below:

```
$resource->location()->first();
```

you can use `dd(variable_name)` before sending the data to the view to get a better idea of how your data is managed